# Delete namespace from App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does anyone know if it possible to delete a namespace i App Engine?

I can iterate over all namespaces but would like to erase a namespace when it is no longer in use.

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A namespace is a property of an entity key. Deleting the namespace really means finding and deleting everything in a given namespace. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataqueries.html lays out the details. Basically, you determine the namespace you want to clear out, switch to it, then nuke the entities there.

If a namespace has a lot of entities, consider using the mapreduce framework (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) to parcel the work up into chunks that will run without timing out.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete all the entities, the namespace should be deleted. If the empty namespace appears to be showing up in [Admin Console](https://appengine.google.com/), this could happen due to some metadata entries being left in the namespace. The newer [Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com) will not show the empty namespace. In order to get the namespace to disappear completely from the drop-down menu of the old [Admin Console](https://appengine.google.com/) please refresh the page after removing all namespace entities.